# Is there anyway redirecting (cin) input from txt file in console twice, for C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, redirect

It is rather convenient to redirect input stream from different txt files in CMD console, since I don't need to write a file name and open it in my code. Like typing `code.exe < input.txt`in windows OS.

However, if I want to redirect two file like input1.txt and input2.txt to two input streams(`cin>>`) located in two positions of my code. How should I deal with it? I just know how to redirect once rather than multiple times. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the two inputs in is the simple problem: `TYPE file1.txt file2.txt > code.exe`. But how would your first `std::cin` statement know which line is the last line of `file1.txt` ?

The normal solution is to use `code.exe file1.txt file2.txt`, and read both files using their own `std::ifstream`.